# Improper integral convergence from minus to positive infinity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Quote from *Essential Calculus: Early Transcendentals*, by James Stewart:

> If $f$ is continuous, then $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{-t}^tf(x)dx$$

I thought this would be true if such a limit exists (aka if the area is convergent from $a \to \infty$ and from $-\infty \to a$), but the book answer-sheet marks it as false. Could anyone explain to me why it is false?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to quantify over $f$.

Comment: @GitGud mind to elaborate? (I forgot to state that $f$ is continuous)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take for example $f(x)=x$. Then
$$
\int_{-t}^t f(x)\,dx=0,
$$
since $f$ is an odd function, and hence the limit $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-t}^t f(x)\,dx$ exists and it is equal to zero. However, the function $f(x)=x$ is NOT integrable on the whole of $\mathbb R$.

Another example is 
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-t}^t \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx=\pi,
$$
although $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ is also NOT integrable on the whole of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks! That made things much clearer. One last thing: would the statement be true if you modified it by saying "if $f$ is integrable on the whole of R then ..." ?

Comment: Yes this is true. Unfortunately, it is not very simple to prove, as we need to use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem!

Comment: I might do some reading on that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The second example is perhaps not completely relevant, since you are talking about Lebesgue integrability (I guess), while the question seems to be about improper Riemann integrals. +1 for the first example, though.